# How can I blur out of a custom element?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, custom-controls

After a regular input, I have a custom widget I am making.

```
<input>

<div class="widget" tabindex="0">
  <input tabindex="-1"/>
</div>
```

- The widget is a `div`
- You tab into the widget (so the `div` has a `tabindex`)
- The widget has an inner `input` which is also focused when the widget's `div` is focused. Some other things happen too (but this is a reduced case!) - that's why I'm not just using another regular input instead of the widget!

Again, tabbing **into** the widget works:

```
var widget = document.querySelector('.widget')
var innerInput = widget.querySelector('input')

widget.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
  widget.classList.add('highlighted')
  innerInput.focus()
})
```

Here's a [working JDFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvbab7xq/)

But tabbing back out of the widget doesn't work. Since the inner `input` is focused, I've attached a `blur` event listener to it which also blurs the widget. I **thought** this would then select the previous, regular input. But it doesn't do anything.

```
// This doesn't work
innerInput.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
  console.log('blurring!')
  widget.classList.remove('highlighted')
  widget.blur();
})
```

**How can I make tabbing out of the custom element work?**

Comment: tab toggle between the inputs in your fiddle, what's wrong with that?

Comment: seems you need to wait a moment: https://jsfiddle.net/rvbab7xq/1/

Comment: those should all be fine, you just need to leapfrog the current execution chain top allow the dom dust to settle. for half a second i was all "this is impossible to fix", then i remembered it's js and anything's possible...

Comment: Thanks Dan. Why do you need to run `widget.tabIndex=0;`? I understand what this does - make it tabbable - but I don't get why it fixes the problem.

Comment: it makes the wrapper un-tabbable just before firing the "find previous tabstop" routine, so that the routine "misses" the wrapper tag, reverting to whatever came before that. a moment later, the wrapper tag tab is re-enabled to allow forward tabbing again, now that it's been successfully skipped...

Comment: Thanks again Dan. Want to add your fiddle and the info re: tabIndex to an answer? I'll award it to you. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dandavis pointed out (Dan, add your own answer!) you can use `tabindex` to remove the tabbability of the widget element, which will move the focused element to the previous element.

```
var widget = document.querySelector('.widget')
var innerInput = widget.querySelector('input')

widget.addEventListener('focus', function(event){
  widget.classList.add('highlighted')
  innerInput.focus()
  widget.tabIndex = -1;
})

innerInput.addEventListener('blur', function(event){
  console.log('blurring!')
  widget.classList.remove('highlighted')
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    widget.tabIndex = 0; 
  }, 0);
})
```

See [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvbab7xq/2/)